# Dyld: Symbol not found: __TMdV12CoreGraphics7CGFloat

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I was coding a SpriteKit game in Xcode 6 using Apple's new programming language, Swift. I'm relatively new to swift and I was able to build the application without errors in Xcode 6 Beta 3. However, ever since Beta 4 was released, I have been unable to run the application on my iPhone, yet the iOS simulator still works.

My iPhone is running iOS 8 Beta 4 and the application if running off Xcode 6 Beta 4 on my Mac, which is using OS X Yosemite Beta 4. When launching the application, I get the error before it open the game's first scene, the full error is here:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMdV12CoreGraphics7CGFloat
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5FA54F59-06DB-4044-AB46-B53431A70E79/Rollathon.app/Rollathon
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5FA54F59-06DB-4044-AB46-B53431A70E79/Rollathon.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5FA54F59-06DB-4044-AB46-B53431A70E79/Rollathon.app/Rollathon
(lldb)
```

My first scene is this:

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreGraphics

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let playBtn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playBtn")
    let title = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "title")
    let settings = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "settings")
    
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // Setup background
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x80D9FF);
        
        // TODO: ADD SETTINGS
        
        // Setup play button
        self.playBtn.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.playBtn.setScale(0.2)
        
        // TODO: Setup title image
        //self.title.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - (self.title.size.height / 1.5))
        
        // Add scene children
        self.addChild(self.playBtn)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playBtn {
                // User has pressed play
                var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
                let skView = self.view as SKView
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
                scene.size = skView.bounds.size
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
            
        }
    }
   
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

It's very simple, which is why I wonder if the issue is caused by another scene; I will upload more scenes if requested.

Comment: Have you tried to clear all derived data? Apple changed the CGFloat implementation in beta 4.

Comment: yup, run Product -> Clean from Xcode. Hold Option key to Clean All.

Comment: Thanks! I cleared all of the delivered date and it works fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the app from your device, do a clean, then run it again. probably an old version of some compiled code was left behind.